# Is there an OOP alternative to hook_entity_operations_alter() in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, hooks

In my custom module, I want to add a new action to the operations menu for each row of the user list that is displayed when going to `/admin/people`. I would like to stay in OOP-land and therefore I'm wondering if there is an alternative to implementing `hook_entity_operations_alter()` in my module? E.g. something that would allow me to create a PHP class for adding my action, or alternatively some way to add the action through the admin interface.

currently I have this code in somemodule.module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_operation_alter()
 */
function somemodule_entity_operation_alter(array &$operations, EntityInterface $entity) {
  if($entity instanceof UserInterface){
    $operations['translate']['title'] = t('Hello @entity_type', array(
      '@entity_type' => $entity->getEntityTypeId(),
    ));
    $operations['translate']['weight'] = 99;
  }
}
```

This works, but as said I would like an alternative that would skip the .module file completely.

Comment: If "translate" is a completely new operation _hook_entity_operation_ is more suitable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operations originally come from [UserListBuilder](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserListBuilder.php/function/UserListBuilder%3A%3AgetOperations/8.2.x). You can extend this class and alter User entity info to point list builder property to your class. The problem is that you need to implement *hook_entity_type_alter* wich is not in OOP land :-).

I suggest you keep this hook until Drupal become a true OOP application.

[This article](https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/alter-or-dispatch-drupal-8-events-versus-alter-hooks) contains a quck comarision of hooks vs OOP events.

Comment: The article is not about what you can decide as a consumer of the list builder class, but what a module developer can decide who provides this class.

Comment: Yes I saw that article, and based on that I was hoping there would have been an event that I could have subscribed to instead of using the hooks to alter the menu. But ok, I'll stick to the hook, since I'd apparently need to use one either way.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not.

Extending the list builder class is something that you should only do for your own entity type, it is *not* a replacement for the hook as there can only be one active list builder class per entity type, so you could easily get into conflicts with other modules.

Plus, to do that, you'd need another hook (hook_entity_type_alter()).

Hooks still exist und unless they are explicitly deprecated in favor of an OOP approach like an event (I'm not aware of a single example for that in Drupal core), it's still the right approach.